# Is it possible to make it so that an application has no icon?

Tags: icons, gnome-classic, nemo, icon-themes

I was wondering, could I make an application not have an icon? I don't mean like "make it a question mark," but I mean like for example how Synapse has no icon when running, would it be possible to *easily* get that property on other applications such as Nemo? Thanks for any help!

Comment: I don't really understand what you are after. Please add a screenshot or something to better explain what you want to archieve.

Comment: When I have the time, I'll pull a screenshot for you.